# Increase Size of TextBox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, textbox, size

I have created a form and am displaying it using a table. One field `Full Name` should be big so I have used `colspan=2` but the Editor or Input box's size is not increased as shown on the image below.

[image]

Here's my code so far. Please help me.

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmpID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 first" })

      <div class="col-md-7">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmpID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td colspan="2">
    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })


      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control long-textbox", disabled = "disabled" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the label (Full Name) and the input field and specify how much width each element should take up.

In my example below width is set to `150px` for the label and `100% - 150px` for the input field. With the `calc()` function you can calculate values in CSS.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* specify how width the text label will be. */
label.full-width{
  width: 150px;
}

/* specify the width of 100% - the width from the label */
input.full-width {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1 - col 1</td>
    <td>row 1 - col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      <label class="full-width">Full Name</label>
      <input class="full-width">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Also, in your code, there's no need to use `colspan=2`. In my example, I used it to illustrate how it can be used. In the example, you span/overlap two column cells with one cell.

Comment: Anyone please help me to get the answer